# Defining integration on manifolds using partitions of unity (Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I have a question on how Spivak defines the integration of a $k$-form on an oriented $k$-dimensional manifold. I've included the relevant section of *Calculus on Manifolds* below. I should mention that when Spivak writes "manifold" they are referring to an embedded submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form on an oriented $k$-dimensional manifold $M$. If there is an orientation-preserving singular $k$-cube $c$ in $M$ such that $\omega =0 $ outside of $c([0,1]^k)$, we define
>   $$\int\limits_M \omega = \int\limits_c \omega.$$
>    Theorem 5-4 shows $\int_M\omega$ does not depend on the choice of $c$. Suppose now that $\omega$ is an arbitrary $k$-form on $M$. There is an open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of $M$ such that for each $U\in \mathcal{O}$ there is an orientation-preserving singular $k$-cube $c$ with $U\subset c([0,1]^k)$. Let $\Phi$ be a partition of unity for $M$ subordinate to this cover. We define
>   $$\int\limits_M \omega = \sum_{\varphi\in \Phi}\int\limits_M \varphi\cdot \omega$$
>   provided the sum converges as described in the discussion preceding Theorem 3-12.

My question is about the open cover $\mathcal{O}$. Spivak never defines what it means for a subset of a manifold $M$ to be open in $M$. In addition to this, partitions of unity subordinate to an open cover have only been constructed in Euclidean space.

If we assume instead that "open" above refers to open in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$, then we encounter another problem. If $k<n$, then $M$ has measure $0$, hence we cannot have an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ contained in $M$. However, Spivak insists that for each $U\in \mathcal{O}$ there is a singular cube $c$ with $U\subset c([0,1]^k)\subset M$.

Is it possible that Spivak meant $M\cap U\subset c([0,1])^k$ instead of $U\subset c([0,1]^k)$?

Comment: An open cover of $M$ consists of open subsets of $M$. He was trying to avoid topological vocabulary, but he's using the subspace topology. A subset of $M$ is open if it is the intersection of an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with $M$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahh I see, that makes sense, thank you :)

Comment: @Tedshifrin Hmm, although if this is the case, how do we go about constructing a partition of unity subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$? In the book, partitions of unity subordinate to a given open cover are constructed in $\mathbb{R}^n$. To do this, we first find a smooth function which is positive on an open rectangle and zero elsewhere. Afterwards, we use the fact that the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is generated by open rectangles. It seems like the same proof wouldn't automatically apply here.

Comment: I'll have to go back and look, but the usual way is to construct them in Euclidean $k$-space and transfer back with charts to the manifold. I personally use balls, not rectangles, but no big deal.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahh I see, it makes sense that we would use charts, since the smoothness of a function $\varphi$ on $M$ is defined in terms of the smoothness of $f^*\varphi$, where $f$ is a chart for $M$, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for the lots of comments, but would it work to construct the partitions of unity in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$? In other words, if $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover for $M$, then for each $U\in \mathcal{O}$ we can find an open subset $U'\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $U=U'\cap M$. If we let $\mathcal{O}'$ denote the collection of such $U'$, then we can find a partition of unity $\Phi$ on $M$ subordinate to $\mathcal{O}'$. We can then take our partition of unity on $M$ subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$ to be the collection of all $\varphi|_M$ for $\varphi\in \Phi$.

Comment: Spivak seems to do his construction for an arbitrary subset $A$ (rather than just for manifolds), so you have no option but to do stuff on open sets in $\Bbb R^n$. I personally don't take this approach.